# Retrieve PostGIS geometry data as WKT using GeoAlchemy without making extra queries

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, postgis, geoalchemy2

I'm using a FastAPI backend to connect to a PostGIS server.
I'm using SQLAlchemy with GeoAlchemy2 as an extension to map the db tables to objects.
One of the tables is called "consortiums" and has a column of type Geometry.
**What I'd like is: to retrieve data from this column under WKT format.**

The relevant part of the table:

```py
class Consortium(Base):
    __tablename__ = "consortiums"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    geometry = mapped_column(Geometry)
```

For now, I have found 2 methods that work:

1. making an explicit query (in this case for just 1 element):

```py
geometry_wkt = session.scalars(select(new_c.geometry.ST_AsText())).first()
```

2. using a `Computed` column:

```py
# declared within the model, right below the geometry column
geometry_wkt: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(Computed("ST_AsText(geometry)"))
```

Another solution I tried is:

```py
from geoalchemy2.functions import ST_AsText

   # added on model
   @hybrid_property
    def geometry_wkt(self):
        return self.geometry.ST_AsText()
```

but when I try to `print` a Consortium model, this seems to just return the function itself instead of the value

```py
print(new_c) # outputs: ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromEWKB(:ST_GeomFromEWKB_1))
```

**Right now I have opted for solution 2 which I'm ok with, I'm just wondering if it is the correct approach for what I'm trying to do or if there is a more efficient or something like a "best practice".**

Answer (score -1):

GeoAlchemy2 has a method called [`to_shape`](https://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shape.html#geoalchemy2.shape.to_shape) from its [shapely integration](https://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shape.html#module-geoalchemy2.shape). This is used as follows:

```
consortium = Session.query(Consortium).first()
shp = to_shape(consortium.geometry)
```

`shp` will be a shapely geometry.
Using [shapely's `to_wkt` method](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.to_wkt.html#shapely-to-wkt) you can get the WKT representation of that geometry without a second query to the DB:

```
to_wkt(shp)
```

Keep in mind that I am not suggesting that your approach is wrong :)
I am just presenting an alternative with a single DB query that is then transformed in the code side of your app!